# Comment vs Answer

Tags: discussion, comments, answers

I was looking at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22023066/nullexception-error) and responded to the poster's question with a concise, two-sentence answer.

> There's nothing in the code you posted that would result in a NullPointerException. You'd have to post the main method, as well as the error message you encounter.

Then I was downvoted a record 7 times. Two people commented on my answer saying "This is a comment, not an answer".

When someone gives an answer that is concise, correct, and polite there is no reason for such widespread disapproval.

When and why is it inappropriate to give an answer over a comment? It seems logical to me that a comment is any response that falls short of being a complete answer. Since my response *was* a complete answer, it seems to be appropriately marked as such.

Comment: Your answer was downvoted 7 times, not 14.  Those 7 downvotes resulted in the loss of 14 reputation.

Comment: Sure, although that's a little pedantic, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: @ktm5124 I try not to take the existing votes into account when I vote on a post.  I never say "hmm, this post is only worth a -2 so I won't vote".  If it is a good post in my opinion, I upvote it, if it is a bad one in my opinion, I downvote it.

Comment: "When someone gives an answer that is concise, correct, and polite there is no reason for such widespread disapproval." - It wasn't an answer. It was basically disputing the premise of the question, and suggesting a change the question. It feels pretty simple to me. You were told why people downvoted... As for Servy's comment being "a little pedantic" - if you're going to include a number in a post, you should make sure it's right.

Comment: Ok, I understand a lot better. Thanks and sorry for my frustration.

Comment: @ktm5124 No.  If find that claiming that there were twice as many downvotes as there actually were to be a pretty big difference, worthy of pointing it out, which is why I pointed it out.

Answer (score 14):

You weren't answering the question.  You were telling the author that his question has problems that result in you being unable to answer it (namely that the code provided doesn't replicate the problem described).  That information should be conveyed through a comment, not an answer.  If you feel sufficently strongly that the question is unanswerable you can also vote/flag to close the question (in addition to commenting, if you like).  The following close reason sounds like it would be applicable to a question like that:

> This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem. Describe your problem in more detail or include a minimal example in the question itself.

If/when the question is edited such that it becomes answerable, you can then post an answer that answers it.  (And reopen it if it was closed.)

Comment: Thank you for the response. However I think that sometimes the line between answerable and not can be a little unclear. Let's say the poster writes a question that contains a clear question, but the formatting is off and it's a wall of text. Does the question pass as answerable? Or must the poster format the question properly before anyone deigns to answer?

Comment: @ktm5124 That's a place where you should generally just edit it yourself.  If the formatting is so off that you find it incomprehensible, and can't imagine editing in the proper formatting without help from the author, then you could consider closing it as "unclear".  If someone is able to figure out what they were asking despite the poor formatting and posts an answer to the question, then that's fine too (but it would be better if they edited the question first).

Comment: @ktm5124: If someone provides an actual answer, that's not much of a problem. If someone posts an "answer" that says "You should format your question better" then that person would be rightly downvoted.

Comment: I see, thanks Servy, Jon Skeet.